# Not Picking up correct story_id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a story reader app where users can upload stories and read them. I have a `story` and a `profile` model. My profile `show` page shows the profile of the current user and display the titles of all the stories he has created. However clicking on any story title link redirects me to the show page of the first story i.e it picks the story id of the first user for every story.

Following are the models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tales, dependent: :destroy
end
```

the controller:

```
class TalesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_story, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tales = Tale.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @tale = current_user.tales.new
  end

  def create
    @tale =current_user.tales.new(tales_params)

    if @tale.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully added stories"
      redirect_to @tale
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error in saving"
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def show       
  end

  def update
    if @tale.update_attributes(tales_params)
      flash[:success] = "Story successfully updated"
      redirect_to @tale
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error in updating"
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @tale.destroy
    redirect_to tales_url
  end

  def edit
  end

  private
  def tales_params
    params.require(:tale).permit(:user_id, :title, :body, :category_id)
  end

  def set_story
    @tale = Tale.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    @tale = current_user.tales.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to tales_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this story" if @tale.nil?
  end
end
```

and the excerpt of view code from `profile/show`

```
 <div>
 <h2> My Stories </h2>
 <ul>
 <% current_user.tales.each do |my_story| %>
   <li><%= link_to my_story['title'], tale_path(current_user) %></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `current_user` to the `tale_path` instead of `my_story`.

Try changing the following:

```
<div>
 <h2> My Stories </h2>
 <ul>
 <% current_user.tales.each do |my_story| %>
   <li><%= link_to my_story['title'], tale_path(current_user) %></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
</div>
```

to the following:

```
<div>
 <h2> My Stories </h2>
 <ul>
 <% current_user.tales.each do |my_story| %>
   <li><%= link_to my_story['title'], tale_path(my_story) %></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
</div>
```